# Using Python in a RC Context Menu to change file names

Tags: python, windows

Win10Pro w/ Python 3.9

I have a side hustle as a photographer, and one of the fun things I've learned to do was create a right-click context menu script that would generate directories for my RAW/PSDs/Edit folders where I need them. There's still however one thing I'd like some help to figure out though.

Whenever Adobe Lightroom exports, it never concatenate a 0 to single digits if there's 10+ files, nore '00' for 100+ files, just a simple -X, -XX, etc.

I'm trying figure out a function do the -0X, -00X respectfully, but the best I could think of was creating a batch file doing a simple RENAME command; yet I can't get it to occur in the directory I've right clicked in explorer.

Here's the code I have for the simple renaming, though only for files *-X.extension:

```
def Reshell():
    ext = ['.arw', '.xmp']

    with open('renum.bat', 'w') as rn:
        for extn in ext:
            for n in range(10):
                if n == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    rn.write('rename *-' + str(n) + extn + ' *-0' + str(n) + extn + '\n')
        rn.close()

    os.system('start cmd.exe @cmd /c renum.bat')
    os.remove('renum.bat')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Reshell()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just do everything in Python, instead of writing a temp `.bat` file, running it, then deleting it when you're done?

Comment: @MattDMo - that was the initial idea, using glob but still have the same issue of how to pull the location from the right click.

Comment: How are you creating right-click menus? Does the mechanism for that have any "knowledge" of the current folder?

Comment: @topsail - no and that's the issue I'm currently trying to figure out.

Comment: I think a lot depends on how you are creating the right click menu. That is the context for calling this code. Unless you want the right click menu to only work in one folder on your computer - in which case, you can just hard code the directory information into the function.

Comment: @topsail - Well, I'm wanting it to work in multiple folders, so I can't hard code the location like that. I do multiple photo-shoots and have all their data in separate folders. so I'd like to just open Windows Explorer to one of those locations, right click, and have the script work in that section.

Comment: @topsail I guess I could make a different script with a browse for DIR function, but that's not as streamlined as I'm hoping for.